# cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int count1(string fileName){

    ifstream infile;
    if (!infile)
        throw "file cannot be opened";
    else{
        int spaces = 0;
        while(getline(fileName,spaces)){
            for(int i=0;i<fileName.size();i++){
                if(fileName[i]==' ')
                    spaces++;
            }
        }
        return spaces;
     }
}

int count2(string fileName){
    int line = 0;
    while(getline(fileName,line)){
        for(int i=0;i<fileName.size();i++)
           if(fileName[i]=='\n')
              line++;
    }
    return line;
}

int count3(string fileName){
    int characters = fileName.size();
    return characters;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int spaces,line,characters = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("fox.txt");
    try{
         int result1 = count1(argv[1]);
         int result2 = count2(argv[1]);
         int result3 = count3(argv[1]);
         cout<<result1<<' '<<result2<<' '<<result3<<endl;
    } catch (const char *e) {
        cout<<e<<endl;
    }
}
```

//The point of this program is to correctly count the number of characters, spaces, and lines in a file. The filename is to be accepted as an argument to the program. I am supposed to check that the file exists and can be opened inside a try-catch block, and throw an exception if the file cannot be opened. I keep getting errors only on line 13 and 24: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’

Comment: Read the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). The arguments you're trying to pass don't match too much with the parameters.

Comment: Wait, so do I just change the argument type? So instead of char I type in string?

Comment: No, you need to read the documentation and read how you call `getline` and find and fix the difference.

Comment: 1st parameter is `std::basic_istream` you're going to read from. Didn't expect that? You have created one in `main` and then you're passing filepath like `getline` will create a new one or locate the existing one. That's nonsense. Also, I don't get how you think about `getline` extracting line of text into `int`.

Comment: I'm not understanding what I'm reading...I get that the arguments I'm trying to pass don't match with the parameter, but the getline syntax is: getline(input,str,delim) where the input is the stream to get data from, and str is the string to put the data into while delim is the delimiter character. When I put fileName as the input, I labeled that as a string in the parameter list, and I put the variable line/spaces to store the information when the function finds a line or space. And since I have no delim, the default delimiter is the end of the line.

Comment: Programming by guessing does not work: your calls to `getline` are obviously complete nonsense. Where did you read that there exists a `getline(string, int)`? Also, why is your indentation so haphazard? Your code is very difficult to read and to follow.

Comment: I'm trying to learn coding the best I can..

Comment: First of all: Try `ifstream infile(filename);` instead of just `ifstream infile;` and change `(getline(fileName,spaces))` to `(getline(infile,spaces));`

Comment: Filename is just that: The name of the file. You need something that represents the actual file. There are several ways to represent a file. You can narrow down which to use by consulting what types of data can be used as input in a call to getline. This is well documented so no point to covering it here.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a number of problems with your code.

Let's start with:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int spaces,line,characters = 0; // Delete this line
    ifstream infile;                // Delete this line
    infile.open("fox.txt");         // Delete this line
    try{
        int result1 = count1(argv[1]);
        int result2 = count2(argv[1]);
        int result3 = count3(argv[1]);
        cout<<result1<<' '<<result2<<' '<<result3<<endl;
    } catch (const char *e) {
        cout<<e<<endl;
    }
}
```

All these are not used in main()! It seems you have a problem understanding the scope of a variable, i.e. when is the variable accessible/valid. A variable declare in main() is not accessible in the function called from main().

So in each of your function you need to open the file again. Something like:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open(filename);
if (!infile)
    throw "file cannot be opened";
```

in all three functions.

And then the getline - use

```
getline(infile,spaces))
```

instead.